# How can I assign values to other class variable in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, class-variables

The below coding is working and I can see the values in my second screen. But I am using the same in other classes with different variables in this format. But it dosent show me the variable if after i type the classname with a dot. I cant figure this out. Is there any way to pass values to other class.

```
        InstallProfiler_2 *installProfiler2 = [[InstallProfiler_2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"InstallProfiler_2" bundle:nil];

        installProfiler2.profilerType2 = profilerType;

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:installProfiler2 animated:NO];
        [installProfiler2 release];
```

Comment: Could you give us what is not working instead of what is working please ?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that:

- You have imported the class header.
- The `@property` declarations are in this header and not a class extension.

`@property` refers to ivars so when you say

> if after i type the classname with a dot

this terminology is incorrect, you probably mean after you start typing the name of the variable which has points to an instance of a class.

**ClassA.h**

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, weak) NSInteger myInt;

@end
```

**ClassA.m**

```
@implementation ClassA

@synthesize myInt = _myInt;

@end
```

**ClassB.m**

```
#import "ClassA.h"   // <- Import the header of the class

@ implementation ClassB

//  .. other methods and stuff

- (void)myMethod;
{
     ClassA *instanceOfClassA = [[ClassA alloc] init];   // <- Working with an instance not a class
     instanceOfClassA.myInt = 1;
}

@end
```

**UPDATE**

Make sure your `@property ()` does not have `readonly` between the round brackets. 
Also make sure you have either `@synthesize`'d the ivar in the implementation or have provided both a getter and a setter for the ivar.

Failing that show some relevant code so we can actually see what your doing - we are answering pretty blindly here.

Comment: He is asking about class variables, not instance variables.

Comment: @coneybeare I'm not so sure I think that may just be the poor phrasing of the question. If you look at the example he said he successfully uses dot notation in the class itself, I thought dot notation only worked on instances?

Comment: Thanks but I getting this error.
    object cannot be set either readonly property or no setter found

Comment: Which attributes did you give to the property corresponding to the class variables you're trying to access ? (nonatomic, retain, assign, etc...)

Comment: @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *variablename

Comment: Do you have this in the implementation `@synthesize variablename;`

Answer (score 0):

The dot syntax is only available with property/synthesize

Comment: yes I used property and also synthesize. but still it wont work.

Comment: Did you correctly import the needed files ? and not only used forward declaration like `@class Toto` ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom setter/getter:

```
+ (BOOL)awesomeClassVar {
    return _classVar;
}

+ (void)setAwesomeClassVar:(BOOL)newVar {
    _classVar = newVar;
}
```

then call as a method from the other class:

```
BOOL theOtherClassVar = [AwesomeClass awesomeClassVar];
[AwesomeClass setAwesomeClassVar:!theOtherClassVar];
```

Comment: THANKS. But could you please explain me in detail? I have variable holds a name in CLASS A. I am setting the values in that class itself. Now I am navigating to CLASS B. here i need to access that value that is set in CLASS A.

Comment: The two methods go in CLASS A. The bottom two lines access the variable from CLASS B.